# Why does having two LEFT JOINS result in additional values?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to combine three tables, one that is related to the other which is related to the other while showing all the rows of one of the tables, USERS.  Then I count how many TCKID from TICKET and TCKID from SEQUENCE each user has.  The tables are related as follows:  USERS <- TICKET <- SEQUENCE

For some reason when my query runs, 'tickets issued' for the first three rows are 2 instead of 1, something that happens after I add my second LEFT JOIN.  Why is that?

```
USERS
+-------+-----------------------+
| USRID |         Name          |
+-------+-----------------------+
|     1 | Lula Wiley            |
|     2 | Isabell Horn          |
|     3 | Usman Hook            |
|     4 | Abdullah Singleton    |
+-------+-----------------------+

TICKET
+-------+-------+
| TCKID | USRID |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |
|     2 |     2 |
|     3 |     7 |
|     4 |    14 |
|     5 |    14 |
|     6 |     6 |
|     7 |     3 |
|     8 |     9 |
+-------+-------+

SEQUENCE
+-------+
| TCKID |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
|     6 |
|     7 |
|     7 |
|     8 |
+-------+
```

---

Here's what my table shows when ran:

```
+-----------------------+----------------+---------------+
|         Name          | Tickets Issued | Total Flights |
+-----------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Lula Wiley            |              2 |             2 |
| Isabell Horn          |              2 |             2 |
| Usman Hook            |              2 |             2 |
| Abdullah Singleton    |              0 |             0 |
+-----------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Here's my code

```
SELECT
    U.Name,
    COUNT(T.USRID) AS 'Tickets Issued',
    COUNT(S.TCKID) AS 'Total Flights'
FROM
    Users U
LEFT JOIN ticket T
    ON U.USRID = T.USRID
LEFT JOIN sequence S        -- Changes Tickets issued 
    ON T.TCKID = S.TCKID
GROUP BY U.Name, U.Phone, T.USRID, U.USRID
```

Comment: Probably use subquery to join the ticket and sequence table first , then put it inside the from to join with user table

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that when you `JOIN` `sequence` to `ticket`, you create a row in the result set for each row in `sequence`. This causes duplication of `USRID` values in `ticket` (try using just `SELECT *` and you will see this), which results in double (or more) counting the `Tickets Issued` value. You can work around this by counting distinct `TCKID`'s in `ticket` instead:

```
SELECT
    U.Name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT T.TCKID) AS 'Tickets Issued',
    COUNT(S.TCKID) AS 'Total Flights'
FROM
    Users U
LEFT JOIN ticket T
    ON U.USRID = T.USRID
LEFT JOIN sequence S        -- Changes Tickets issued 
    ON T.TCKID = S.TCKID
GROUP BY U.Name, U.USRID
ORDER BY U.USRID
```

Output:

```
Name                Tickets Issued  Total Flights
Lula Wiley          1               2
Isabell Horn        1               2
Usman Hook          1               2
Abdullah Singleton  0               0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oAU5ehi4CrgGkGaEkod3CM/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    U.Name,
    COUNT(T.USRID) AS 'Tickets Issued',
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM sequence S
        WHERE S.TCKID = T.TCKID
    ) AS 'Total Flights'
FROM
    Users U
LEFT JOIN ticket T
    ON U.USRID = T.USRID
GROUP BY U.Name, U.Phone, T.USRID
```

or

```
SELECT
    U.Name,
    COUNT(T.USRID) AS 'Tickets Issued',
    T_TOTAL_FLIGHT.total_flights AS 'Total Flights'
FROM
    Users U
LEFT JOIN ticket T
    ON U.USRID = T.USRID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TCKID, COUNT(*) AS total_flights
    FROM sequence
    GROUP BY TCKID
) T_TOTAL_FLIGHT ON T.TCKID = T_TOTAL_FLIGHT.TCKID
GROUP BY U.Name, U.Phone, T.USRID
```